# Is there a way to limit the live api credentials to read-only?

Tags: paypal

I was asking myself, how much damage someone can cause, if he gets the api credentials in his hands. So based on this worry, i am asking this question here.

When i speak about "api credentials", i speak about the ones, which i get explained [in this tutorial](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/wiki/Going-Live).

Comment: What would "read only" do to mitigate anything? You can [manage](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/apiCredentials/) (change/regenerate, etc.) as you deem fit/necessary...Hth.

Comment: @EdSF i updated my question to make it more clear. i am using the github php sdk, theres a tutorial howto get api credentials. and _there_ is no way to limit something, when i log into paypal.com: My Account > Profile > My Selling Tools - there is nothing i can change.